# Webview doesnt load image with String Html

Tags: android, android-webview

Im making an app in which i show one wikipedia page, for testing im create a new project.

```
    mvw.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mvw.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    mvw.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    mvw.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mvw.setWebViewClient(new mostrarEnAplicaion());
    String htmlString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = \"text-align:center\"><img src=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=52633874#/media/File:Wat_Phra_Mahathat_Woramahawihan,_Nakhon_Si_Thammarat.jpg\" alt=\"pageNo\" height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\"></body></html>";
    mvw.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,htmlString,"text/html","UTF-8","about:blank");
```

If I load the URL directly works fine

```
mvw.loadUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Mar%C3%ADa_del_Naranco");
```

I have the permission.INTERNET on the Manifest but doesnt work, anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After look for a while, I just see that in this line

```
mvw.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,htmlString,"text/html","UTF-8","about:blank");
```

I only have to change the null (BaseUrl) for the url of the website in which the images are storage, in this case `"https://en.wikipedia.org/"`